# Refer to index value present in same row

Tags: excel, moving-average, refer

For a large series of numbers I would like to find out a certain moving average. 
I want for example in T(750) the average of K2:K(index). This certain index can be found in the same row, in column B. So in Cell B750.
How can I do this?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: In B750, or B(index)?

Comment: In B750

I will adjust it in the original post

Comment: Then my answer will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX():

```
=AVERAGE($K$2:INDEX($K:$K,B750))
```

Or to ensure no errors as @Jeeped suggested

```
=AVERAGE($K$2:INDEX($K:$K,MAX(B750,2))
```

Otherwise you will get errors if B750 is text or null.

Comment: `=AVERAGE($K$2:INDEX($K:$K, MAX(2, B750)))`